# Как построить график pandas по 2м столбцам, если они не имеют названия?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

У меня есть csv-файл с данными вида как на скриншоте [image: скрин]
Пытаюсь использовать функцию библиотеки df.plot.scatter(), но из-за того, что столбцы не имеют названий - не знаю как записать данные, пыталась через индексы, но вылезают ошибки... Нужно просто построить точечный график

Comment: Ссылка на исходные данные: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/Zq_mJWTsimeLew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваши столбцы имеют названия, просто они не строковые, а числовые. Это именно 1, 2, 3 в виде целых чисел, а не в виде строк '1', '2', '3'.

Код для моделирования ваших данных:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame((np.random.rand(100, 4)-0.5)/100)
df.iloc[:,1] = np.random.choice(2, size=100)
df = df.drop(columns=0)
df
```

Содержимое нескольких первых строк `df`:

|  | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0.001186 | -0.002849 |
| 1 | 1 | -0.001516 | -0.003497 |
| 2 | 0 | 0.001159 | 0.002624 |

Попробуем нарисовать графики. Помним, что названия колонок - это числа 1, 2, 3.

```py
df.plot.scatter(x=1, y=2);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Да, мы увидим две вертикальные линии из точек. Ну так это потому, что колонка 1 состоит только из значений 0 и 1, вот по этим линиям на оси `x` и выстроились все точки графика.

```py
df.plot.scatter(x=2, y=3);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот это уже вполне нормальный график рассеяния, потому как колонки 2 и 3 достаточно хорошо разбросаны.

**UPDATE**

Хорошо, смотрим на ваших данных, которые вы предоставили. Отрисовка в точности тем же кодом, которым я рисовал на своих сгенерированных данных:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

df = pd.read_csv('out_vectors.csv', sep=';', decimal=',', header=None, index_col=0)
df.plot.scatter(x=2, y=3);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Смотрим график. Ну тут видно, что у вас есть сильные выбросы, особенно выделяется один выброс в колонке `2` аж за `-0.7`, из-за этих выбросов диаграмма рассеяния слилась практически в одну линию. Хотите рассмотреть детали графика получше? Можно ограничить его для этого по оси `x`:

```py
df.plot.scatter(x=2, y=3);
plt.xlim(-0.025, 0.025);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данные у вас всё-равно кластеризуются в некие пятна, ну так это тоже нормально для данных, которые не являются случайными.

**UPDATE2**

Раскраска делается с помощью параметра `c=`, но с вашими цветами всё сливается в дефолтной палитре, поэтому нужно ещё [подбирать палитру](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) и указывать её через `cmap=`.

```py
df.plot.scatter(x=2, y=3, c=1, cmap='tab20');
plt.xlim(-0.025, 0.025);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У вас там далеко не только 0 и 1, а там значения вплоть до 11, поэтому цветов много. Но в основном 0 и 1, поэтому палитру нужно брать такую, где 0 и 1 различаются, не сливаются.

Comment: теперь моя линия просто стала диагональной, хотя выбираю 2 и 3 колонки...

Comment: и не очень понимаю для чего нужен код в самом начале вашего ответа? я вижу, что там рандомные числа, удаление столбца, индексация. но зачем это?

Comment: @Юлия Ну а как вы предлагаете что-то делать с вашими данными - набирать их со скриншота? Я этим кодом пытаюсь получить что-то похожее с виду на ваши данные. Судя по всему, у вас просто такие данные, раз там получается диагональ, значит данные этих двух колонок в вашем случае не случайно разбросаны, а довольно конкретно коррелируют между собой.

Comment: я могу прикрепить к вопросу файл с данными, данные не должны так выглядеть, это точно

Comment: Прикрепляйте. Так всем будет проще )

Comment: я прикрепила данные

Comment: @Юлия Дополнил ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое! И можете, если Вам несложно, подсказать как раскрасить кластеры в разные цвета (столбец с индексом 1)?

Comment: Там всё просто. Добавил. И почитайте документацию, там же реально всё есть, нужно только читать.

Comment: спасибо Вам огромное за помощь, Вы невероятно помогли мне!

Answer (score 1):

Вывод скаттер-плота из данных датафрейма с колонками, в которых нет названий делается элементарно:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df=pd.DataFrame([[2,1],[3,6],[4,2]])
print (df)
plt.scatter(df[0],df[1])
```

Если очень хочется именно через `df.plot.scatter()` то так

```
cols = df.columns.tolist()
df.plot.scatter(cols[0],cols[1])
```

Однако!!! Поскольку у вас на приложенном рисуночке сверху столбцов стоят циферки, причем отсчет идет не с нуля (сравните мой пример, где действительно, названия столбцов отсутствуют), то что-то мне подсказывает, что на самом деле имена столбцов у вас есть, только вы этого не понимаете.

Удачи.

P.S.  Дополнение к ответу по мотивом комментария ТС.
Поскольку автор вопроса вместо того, что-бы сесть, почитать документацию и спокойно разобраться, решила поминусовать меня -  ну типа "график все равно выглядит неправильно", решил дополнить свой ответ, показав ПОШАГОВО, как и что надо делать.

Поскольку ТС не удосужилась даже прочитать правила этого сайта, которые требуют предоставлять воспроизводимый пример (другими словами ей лень было привести свой набор данных так, что-бы с ним можно было работать) привожу искусственный набор данных, который мне не лень было набрать:
Итак:

Шаг 1.
Создаем тренировочный набор данных:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame([[0,1,1],[0,2,4],[0,3,3],[0,4,5],[0,5,7]])
print(df)
```

Имеем:

```
   0  1  2
0  0  1  1
1  0  2  4
2  0  3  3
3  0  4  5
4  0  5  7
```

Шаг 2.
Удаляем из него нулевой столбец:

```
df.drop(df.columns[[0]], axis = 1, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Привели датафрейм к виду, как у ТС в вопросе:

```
   1  2
0  1  1
1  2  4
2  3  3
3  4  5
4  5  7
```

Шаг 3.
Рисуем график, как было предложено в ответе выше:

```
cols = df.columns.tolist()
df.plot.scatter(cols[0],cols[1])
```

получаем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите, все рисуется правильно.

Если у ТС *"точки расположены просто по вертикальной прямой"* то переходим к

Шаг 4.
рекомендую смотреть, где ЕЩЕ у нее ошибки в коде, а не минусовать правильные ответы. Ну или хотя-бы выполнять условия формулировки вопросов на сайте.

Удачи.

Comment: Нумерация в названиях столбцов начинается не с нуля, так как нулевой столбец был удален за ненадобностью. 
Пробовала по вашему примеру (как и писала в самом начале, что пробовала использовать элементарную индексацию), но график выглядит неправильно!
И что за "читать не пробовали?", я просто прошу подсказки, а Вы с такой грубостью мне отвечаете.

Comment: и да, вылезающие ошибки я устранила, но график все также выглядит неверно (точки расположены просто по вертикальной прямой)

Comment: Дополнил ответ выше. Смотрите и исправляйте свои ошибки.

Comment: Господи, я не понимаю откуда в Вас столько токсичности. Во-первых, я не имею права минусовать ответы, так как у меня слишком маленькая репутация на сайте, во-вторых, Вы могли просто спокойно попросить меня скинуть исходные данные, которые мне было бы не лень Вам скинуть, так произошло просто от забывчивости (как будто я сижу только над этим одним вопросом).

Comment: @passant При всём уважении, вам реально нужно подумать над стилем общения с задающими вопросы. Да, они бывают ленивы, бывают непонятливы, но это не повод к такой экспрессии, извините :)